# webservice calling another webservice

Tags: web-services, wsdl, weblogic

Does anyone know how to call one webservice from another webservice? Is it even possible? I am using weblogic but it doesnt really go into details with regards to how the WSDLs would change from the invoking web service to the second one.

Any tips on how I would call one form another would be appreicated.

thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for web logic, but for Web services, and of course it is possible to call Web services from Web services. The WSDL does not change at all since it only describes the public interface of your service, which does not change if you decide to out-source the internal logic to another service. What you probably need to do is to generate a Web service client based on the WSDL of the second service. This generated code can then be used by the first service.

As an alternative you may want to look into WS-BPEL. It is a domain specific language for composite services, i.e. for stitching multiple WSDL services together in order to provide a higher-level WSDL service. [Eclipse BPEL Designer](http://eclipse.org/bpel/) could be starting point for the modelling tool, [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/) for the runtime.