# How to use service reference in a service asmx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm new to C# and asp.net, but i will try to explain as good as i can.

I want to add a service reference from `http://www8.something.com/service1.asmx` to a service called `localhost/WeatherParser.asmx` in which I could use the methods from the service1.asmx.

I have tried adding service reference to my `default.aspx` like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510953/calling-asmx-from-c-sharp-server-side-endpoint-element-matching-this-contract-c) and it worked ok, but how do i use a service in another service ?

Is it even possible and how ? Please give some - Explanations,examples and reference to another sources.

What it looks like in my head:

```
DefaultApp < Weatherservice.aspx < Servicereference(http://www8.something.com/service1.asmx)
```

If there are some other ways than I were able to think of please share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are asking `is it possible to call web service from another web service?` , the answer is : Yes , according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751089/webservice-calling-another-webservice).And [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/calling-a-web-service-into-another-web-service-application/) should help you find out how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

So first you create the Web service that you would like to use

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
public class MyWebService{
    public string RunCodeThroughWebService()
    {
        //Do some stuff to the server or whatever you want to do
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to call the web method in C# but here it is in JavaScript

```
function runWebService{
    $.ajax({
        url: '/webservices/MyWebService.asmx/RunCodeThroughWebService',
        data: { },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'string',
        timeout: 50000,
        error: function(){  

        },
        success: function(result){              
            $('body').html(result); 
        }
    });         
}
```